# Is there a way to write code to go to the previous activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Right now in my android app a user presses a button to go to another activity, and then must press the back button on android to return to the previous activity.  Can I have a button on my app and write code to go to the previous activity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the easiest way, you code write a code where your current activity is closed on a particular event, say on a button press. the method to be called is `finish()`

This way, when your current activity is finished, you are taken back to your previous activity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Ofcourse. : See the [vogella article](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#explicitintents)